Freeradius SQL query for disconnected in specific date
Is there some way to run a SQL query in the freeradius database to find disconnected users in some specific data range?
I'm trying something like this:
SELECT ra.username
FROM radacct ra
WHERE ra.acctstarttime NOT BETWEEN '2024-03-01' AND '2024-03-31'
  AND ra.acctstoptime IS NOT NULL

But this way doesn't work well, as it returns users who could have logged in 2024-02-29.
I need to find who pass the whole data range disconnected, independent of his logout date.

Welcome to the SO community. The community will help you with issues, but there are some expectation of you. Please spend a few minuets to Take the Tour and review [ask]. Then update your question to include table definition(s) (DDL), sample data, and expected results. All as formatted text or even better a fiddle, but - no images.

You need to exclide all dates before your date to
So make this:
SELECT ra.username
FROM radacct ra
WHERE ra.acctstarttime NOT BETWEEN '2024-03-01' AND '2024-03-31'
AND ra.acctstarttime > '2024-03-31'
AND ra.acctstoptime IS NOT NULL


This works, but it doesn't solve my problem
I need to find all logins that had no connection on the filtered date.
This way I find all the records that are not in my filter.
Ok, but he had the connection on the date, which appears in another record.
Briefly, I need to fetch all logins, which did not have acctupdatetime, or acctstarttime in the date range.
I want to find logins, not connections

That is hard to grasp without data and wanted result, tomakeit clearer which records you want a full [mre]
